# Media Player project in c#

Tags: c#, video, flv

I am working on one of the media project (windows application). In this the flv, avi and mpeg are the main file types which i have to play in application. I can use wmpLib, but it will not play flv files. So what procedure should i follow and what tools or libraries should i use.Is there any free opensource libraries to do media work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use ffmpeg lib see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Using_FFMpeg.aspx), I think it would be easy to convert to another format using that for playback I don't really know, maybe you can take a look at the source of vlc or take a look at some flv opensourced player around.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [the right direct show filters](http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/how_to_play_flv_files.cfm) installed media player will play flv files.